# C++ : Binary tree - Remove children from parent vector

Tags: c++, tree, functional-programming

i have this structure:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <vector>

typedef int T;
class tree; 

class node {
    T info;
    std::vector<node*> children;
    friend class tree;
public:
    typedef std::vector<node*>::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin() {
        return children.begin();
    }
    iterator end() {
        return children.end();
    }
    T get() {
        return info;
    }
};

class tree {
    node* r;
    void del(node* v) {
        if (v == NULL) return;
        for (node::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it)    
            del(*it);
        delete v;
    }
public:
    tree() : r(NULL) { }
    node* add(T info, node* parent) {
        node* v = new node;
        v->info = info;
        if (parent != NULL) parent->children.push_back(v);
        else {
            if (r != NULL) del(r);
            r = v;
        }
        return v;
    }
node* add(T info) {

        return add(info, NULL);
    }
    node* root() { return r; }
    void remove(node* v) {
        if (r == v) r = NULL;
        else { /* remove v from the list of children of its parent */ }
        del(v);
    }
};
```

I need to Complete the function remove by deleting the node v from the list of its parents. To do so efficiently, i would add to the node class a pointer to its parent and update the add function accordingly.
This is my solution
I modify the add function with:

```
 node* add(T info, node* parent) {
    node* v = new node;
    v->info = info;
    if (parent != NULL) {
         parent->children.push_back(v);
         v->parent=parent; }
    else {
         if (r != NULL) del(r);
         r = v;
         r->parent=null;
          }
    return v;
}
```

and i modify the remove function as:

```
  void remove(node* v) {
        if (r == v) r = NULL;
        else { 
         v->parent->children.pop_back(v);  
         }
        del(v);
    }
```

Is this conceptually correct? Unfortunately the `pop_back method` of the class `vector`do not allows this kind of arguments so this return an error. 
Is this correct or should i use another implementation?

Sorry, i'm not so familiar with c++ . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`pop_back` removes the last element from the vector - whichever it is...

Try this instead:

```cpp
std::vector<node*>::iterator entry = std::find(v->parent->begin(), v->parent->end(), v);
if(entry != v->parent->end())
    v->parent->erase(entry);
```

Or shorter:

```cpp
auto entry = std::find(v->parent->begin(), v->parent->end(), v);
/* ... */
```

A variant would be using std::remove:

```cpp
v->parent->erase(std::remove(v->parent->begin(), v->parent->end(), v), v->parent->end());
```

`std::remove` removes *all* occurences of v within the given range (suppose it is only one...) by moving all subsequent elements the appropriate number of positions towards the beginning (if one element has already been removed, one position, if two elements, two positions, ...) and returns an iterator to the position one past the last one still being in use. The elements starting from here are, however, still left in the vector (or list or ...), so you have to remove these elements yet, which is done by the second variant of `vector::erase` function...

About the concept: There is one point appearing critical to me: If parent is null, you want to delete the root. But what, if root has children itself? Will you delete them recursively in the del function? And are you sure that you really want to replace the entire tree already contained? Possibly it is better to make `r` a child of `v` then?

But now don't interpret this as "you should do it that way" - it is only a recommendation to think about - but I don't know your requirements, so it is up to you to decide... Only one important thing: do not forget to delete children of a node if you delete it, otherwise you have a memory leak...

Apart from that, your concept looks OK to me at a first glance...

**Edit:** Answering the question in your comment: The appropriate destructor would look like this:

```cpp
~node()
{
    for(node* n : children)
    {
        delete n;
    }
}
```

This deletes recursively all nodes of all children. All you then need to do to clear the entire tree is

```cpp
delete r;
r = nullptr;
```

e. g.:

```cpp
void clear()
{
    delete r;
    r = nullptr;
}
~tree()
{
    clear();
}
```

I assume it was not your intention to allow this either, but you would get into deep trouble if your node was inserted in more than one children vector!

So if you plan to reparent nodes later, keep in mind to remove a node from its previous parents list then. And if you want to keep some child nodes, you need to take them out of the tree first, of course.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions are right. This is an exercise so i have to respect the structure and the implementation. Btw, i would ask, how can i make a Deconstructor of the tree, in a  way to delete all the nodes of the tree?

Comment: thanks man. Honestly i did not know that style used for the "for" instruction that's why i was a bit stuck.  It's not a good practice to build a destroctor of a class, that destroy items that are not declared in that class i suppose .... that's why in the ~tree() we delete just r, and in ~node() we delete all the nodes... ! @Aconcagua

Comment: @rollotommasi Actually, it is not a problem to delete the nodes from within tree (unless destructor was private). However, you have to do it right: Imagine your del function accepted a node*, iterated over all the child nodes, calling del on them recursively, and then deleted the node it got passed. Then in the ~tree() destructor, you would simply call `if(r) del(r);`. This should work, too, but the destructor variant above is yet a bit simpler...

Comment: so i would have used the ` for(node* n : children){...}` even in my `del` function to delete all nodes, and then i would have called del(r) from my `~tree()` ?

Comment: @rollotommasi Yes. But then after the loop, you still need to delete the node itself passed to del function. By the way: the (for node* : children) is just syntactic sugar, it actually is converted to the iterator loop you originally had, and spares you additionally the need of having to dereference the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i made something like that:

```
~tree()
{
    for(node::iterator it=r->children.begin(); it!=r->children.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->info=NULL;
        node* tmp= new node;
        tmp=(*it);
        delete tmp;   
    }
    r->info=NULL;
    delete r; //Dealloco la memoria riservata ad r
}
```

Comment: Edited your answer to make it a code section instead of citation. You should only paste the code relevant for the solution - the output to std::cout is not, in this case, so I removed it... However, you have a memory leak!

Comment: `node* tmp = new node;` creates a new node, then `*it` is *copied* into and you delete the copy again; `*it` in constrast is never deleted; additionally, you do not consider to delete the children of the children!

Comment: Yes i noticed it too late (lol). By the way xcode returns me an error if i try to `delete(*it)`! For deleting children of children there is the del function wich should delete only the children of each nodes passed. So i can call again `del(*it)` and immediatly later  `delete(*it)`. !  am i right?

Comment: Have a look at my answer - you are really easily out of trouble if you delete the chilren right in the node's destructor... \*i gives you a pointer (node\*) - why should you not be able to delete it (unless you deleted it previously! - then you have another bug, though).

Comment: What's about that?                                                                         `for(node::iterator it=r->children.begin(); it!=r->children.end(); ++it){
            (*it)->info=NULL;
            (*it)->children.erase(find((*it)->children.begin(), (*it)->children.end(), (*it)));
            *it=NULL;
            delete (*it);`

Comment: Do you really expect current node being in its own children list??? And if you do *it = NULL, you cannot delete it afterwards...